# Manipulating variables in windows

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, cmd

I know there are a few things you can do directly with a variable, such as cut off ends of the variables via `%var:~0,4%`, or even do character replacement via `%var:/=-%`. What are these features called? And does anyone have a link to documentation for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the old dos string manipulation. See http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Comment: That's an awesome link. Thanks.

Comment: @NickMartin: What "old dos string manipulation"? These features first appeared with new CMD.EXE Windows DOS emulator. There are no such things in "old dos" COMMAND.COM shell!

Comment: Hey, you're right! I guess you learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "Environment variable substitution" as described in `SET /?` (although this omits to mention parameter substitution commands like `%~nxN` for extracting a file name from a path passed as the Nth command line argument).

Comment: Those can be found with FOR /?